# Issues in creating hierarchical columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Just approached the hierarchical columns in pandas. The original dataframe (df) has 27 columns and looks like the following (Ticker is the index):

```
        Report Date   Shares        Gross Profit      ...
Ticker                                                                          
AAPL    2010-07-31    347000000.0   543000000.0       ...     
AAPL    2010-10-31    344000000.0   548000000.0       ...
AAPL    2011-01-31    347000000.0   556000000.0       ...
AAPL    2011-04-30    347000000.0   580000000.0       ...
AAPL    2011-07-31    348000000.0   591000000.0       ...
```

I'd like to modify the column structure so that the first level is **Report Date**, the second level is the columns **Shares** and **Gross Profit**. I tried to create a new dataframe with this structure for just one ticker (AAPL), this is the code I used:

```
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Report Date'], df[['Shares', 'Gross Profit']]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.loc['AAPL'], columns=col)
```

It seems working apparently, but there are just NaN:

```
Report Date 2010-07-31           2010-10-31               \
            Shares  Gross Profit Shares Gross Profit   
Ticker                                                                
AAPL        NaN     NaN          NaN          NaN   
AAPL        NaN     NaN          NaN          NaN   
AAPL        NaN     NaN          NaN          NaN   
AAPL        NaN     NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Moreover, the shape exploded to **(78, 112668)**. Can anybody spot the error? I guess it's in MultiIndex.from_product but cannot understand where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

This question can be solved by [df.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) if we aim at producing the transposed version of the desired output first. You can easily set the double-leveled `MultiIndex` before `df.transpose()`.

```
df_want = df.melt(id_vars="Report Date", value_vars=["Shares", "Gross Profit"])\
    .sort_values(["Report Date", "variable"])\
    .set_index(["Report Date", "variable"])\
    .transpose()
```

### Result

```
print(df_want)

Report Date   2010-07-31               ...   2011-07-31             
variable    Gross Profit       Shares  ... Gross Profit       Shares
value        543000000.0  347000000.0  ...  591000000.0  348000000.0

[1 rows x 10 columns]
```

N.B. **The problem of the original attempt**: IMO a better data wrangling strategy is to let the desired indexes/columns be *produced naturally* within the data processing pipeline or set via standard Pandas APIs, especially when the names or indexes/columns are already present in the source dataframe.

Edit: "Produce the desired index/columns naturally" means to NOT compute them outside the `df.f1(...).f2(...).f3(...)...` pipeline and assign the externally generated index/columns to the output DataFrame. Such approach can produce less error-prone and more maintainable code in general.

In other words, manually generating indexes or column names is not likely a Pandastic way to go, except maybe for pre-allocation of empty dataframes.

### Generalization to Multiple Tickers

I think there is a great chance that dealing with multiple tickers at once would be a realistic use case. So I also provide such a generalized version just in case. This solution is of course also applicable for single-ticker dataframes.

**Data**

```
        Report Date   Shares        Gross Profit
Ticker                                                              
AAPL    2010-07-31    347000000.0   543000000.0   
AAPL    2010-10-31    344000000.0   548000000.0 
AAPL    2011-01-31    347000000.0   556000000.0 
AAPL    2011-04-30    347000000.0   580000000.0 
AAPL    2011-07-31    348000000.0   591000000.0
GOOG    2011-07-31    448000004.0   691000000.0 
GOOG    2010-07-31    447000004.0   643000000.0 
GOOG    2010-10-31    444000004.0   648000000.0 
GOOG    2011-01-31    447000004.0   656000000.0 
GOOG    2011-04-30    447000004.0   680000000.0
```

**Code**

```
df_want = df.reset_index()\
    .melt(id_vars=["Ticker", "Report Date"], value_vars=["Shares", "Gross Profit"])\
    .sort_values(["Ticker", "Report Date", "variable"])\
    .pivot(index="Ticker", columns=["Report Date", "variable"], values="value")
```

**Result**

```
print(df_want)

Report Date   2010-07-31               ...   2011-07-31             
variable    Gross Profit       Shares  ... Gross Profit       Shares
Ticker                                 ...                          
AAPL         543000000.0  347000000.0  ...  591000000.0  348000000.0
GOOG         643000000.0  447000004.0  ...  691000000.0  448000004.0
[2 rows x 10 columns]
```

I am using pandas v1.1.3 and python 3.7 on a 64-bit debian 10 laptop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the code for handling one ticker works perfectly, though the code for multiple tickers produces an odd error (Pycharm): "NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time". Any idea why? Also, can you clarify the meaning of "to let the indexes/columns be produced naturally within the processing pipeline or set via standard Pandas APIs" ?

Comment: 1. No. I implemented this with Pycharm. It's fine on my side (again). Please make sure your pandas version is up-to-date and you have cleaned up previous results. 2. The required explanation is added below that paragraph.